# Mechanics ODE Problem Particle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I have a particle of mass $M$ which moves with a velocity $v$, such that;

$$Mv' = -Mg - kv^2$$ where 
$g$ and $k$ are positive,
and its initial velocity is $U$, i.e $v(0) = U$.

I am then told that the particle travels until it becomes stationary, at a distance $D$ from it's original position.

I am looking for an expression for this distance, but I am unable to solve non linear second order ODEs so I am wondering if there is a different approach available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ODE is nonlinear, but first order (because there is only a first derivative to $t$). To solve it, use the method of [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: Ok, so once I have solved the ODE for $v$, do i integrate again to find the distance?

Comment: Well, I leave it up to your physical insight to answer that question. Also, it is worthwhile to ask yourself what 'stationary' means (concerning the limits of your integration).

Comment: This is where I'm a little confused, I've found an expression for $v$, now, do I set $v=0$ in this expression and solve for $t$, then integrate the velocity between $0$ and the expression I just found?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do.